# SEO for multiple domains for the same site

Tags: domains, 301-redirect, rel-canonical

I have a .co.uk site that ranks well (position no. 4 in Google and no. 1 in Bing). After 5 years, I've finally got round to registering the .com for the same site. As this doesn't need to be a .co.uk I'd effectively like this to be the main site from now on.

How will this impact my SEO? I can set a canonical URL to indicate the .com as the primary domain which would be the obvious choice if I'd registered the .com 4 years ago. I also know that doing nothing and keeping both domains pointing to the same site can have an adverse effect.

I have read many similar questions, but not able to find an exact answer. Any guidance appreciated. Thanks

Comment: The co.uk site and the .com site will be considered different sites regardless of the content or what you do. For this reason, there will be a significant disruption making the change. Your co.uk domain has trust factors that have been established while your .com site will have little. As well, links to the site are a factor. These aside, the content itself will perform the same. It will simply be a matter of patience as the new site builds trust and links. In the end, the .com site will reach a larger audience providing that it is not a local site such as a London retail store or restaurant.

Comment: Ideally you should 301 to the new domain since canonical links does not tell Google your site has moved. Tell Google your domain has changed within Google Search Console and then setup a 301 redirect... those who attempt to access the old site will still be able to access their pages.

Comment: Thanks to both. I was hoping to avoid the disruption in making the changes. Also it's a wordpress site, so I can write some code to only 301 when on the .co.uk.
I thought that two sites with the same content could possibly adversely affect the .com site.
Funnily enough, there aren't many inbound links (less than 10) and on social sites so I'm fairly sure most are "nofollow".

Comment: Okay. No harm no foul. Just move your content, creat a simple 301 redirect, and be patient. It will work out okay in time. It just takes time. Search engines are not real time. It can take months, but in the end, you should end up in a good place. Cheers!!